# The argument type 'IconData?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData'

Tags: flutter, icons

if you could help me with this case please.

I am with this problem wanting to assign some icons and I am getting the following error

Home_page.dart

```
final categoryItem = _CategoryItem(
          icon: servicesProvider.icons[category.icon],
          label: category.name,
          isSelected: servicesProvider.category.id == category.id,
          onTap: () => servicesProvider.selectCategory(category),
        );
```

services_provider.dart

```
 final Map<String, IconData >  icons = {
'scissors': FontAwesome.scissors,
'knife': RpgAwesome.knife,
'mask': FontAwesome5.mask,
'pump_soap': FontAwesome5.pump_soap,
'hand_sparkles': FontAwesome5.hand_sparkles,
'face': Icons.face,
'airline_seat_legroom_extra': Icons.airline_seat_legroom_extra,
'person_booth': FontAwesome5.person_booth,
```

};

Comment: Try icon: servicesProvider.icons[category.icon]!, 
added "!" at end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a fallback icon or add a bang operator because `servicesProvider.icons`'s result might be nullable:

```dart
icon: servicesProvider.icons[category.icon] ?? Icon(Icons.add),
```

or

```dart
icon: servicesProvider.icons[category.icon]!,
```